# ActionScript 3 Simple Projectile Pathing

Tags: actionscript-3

Good evening (at the time of writing)

The research I've done on this topic has turned up numerous fruitful code blocks regarding various situations similar to mine, but not quite identical.  If one exists which I have not uncovered, I would be grateful for a link!

I have a few pertinent criteria, all on a 2d plane, and the question is related to 2d projectile pathing:

1) Object A: position ax,ay

2) Object B: position bx, by

3) Object P: (projectile) origin position bx,by

Object P leaves object B's X/Y position at a static velocity, traveling toward object A's X/Y position.

Objects A and B continue to move along their paths, irrespective of object P's trajectory.  Object P continues to move from ax,ay to bx,by and beyond.  I think I just need the angle and velocity, and don't need to continue to track beyond that (just increment movement steps accordingly till off-stage, where the object is disposed).

I'm working in Actionscript 3, any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most case in 2D x-y plane, it is usually easier to handle movement and momentum in planar(separate in x-axis and y-axis) fashion than polar(angle+distance) fashion. I couldn't get the exact behaviour of projectile you want, so I assume you want a simple, dumbfire-rocket style projectile (which keeps initial direction).

:: 1. Projectile initiation ("Firing" of projectile)

```
var duration:int //(duration of flight(until getting to (ax,ay) described in number of frames)
var spdX:Number //(x-axis part of speed, described in pixels per frame)
var spdY:Number //(y-axis part of speed, described in pixels per frame)

spdX=(bx-ax)/duration;
spdY=(by-ay)/duration;
```

:: 2. Projectile movement (listen to ENTER_FRAME Event, executed once per frame)

```
projectile.x+=spdX;
projectile.y+=spdY;
```

:: if you want to change velocity of projectile, simple multiplication will handle it.

```
public function adjustSpeed(ratio:Number):void
{
    spdX*=ratio;
    spdY*=ratio;
}
```

Comment: Appreciated!  The distance between objects A & B is variable (moving ships, scrolling shooter game).  The duration set at say, 60 (frames) causes the projectile to travel slowly between them if they're close together.  Other than that, it's working just as I hoped.

Comment: If I want the projectile to travel from object B to object A at the same speed regardless of the location of object B or A (like a bullet), how would it be changed?  Thank you!

Comment: Just sussed out - the 'rocket' keeps initial direction AND speed.  Thoughts?  Trying to work it out myself.  Thanks!

Comment: (Laughs) You're right, rockets accelerates. I just meant to refer something that does not have guided-missile-like behavior.

Comment: And, in this case, you can just pre-calculate duration with distance between Obj A & B. calculating distance will be easy using static methods in Point class, or you can just do it yourself with Math class.

Comment: duration = distance(calculated)/speed(you set it). Of course you can consider implementing more verbose approach using polar-coordinate fashion, using Point.polar / Math.atan2

Comment: Just one more thing : If your code is for shooter game, then accuracy is an issue. You'd better use Number instead of int for var duration, or it will cause significant loss of precision!